# How can I have a single data collection of multiple derived types in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, inheritance

I'm not sure if I phrased my question appropriately, but consider the following scenario:

I have an abstract class called `Card`. The `Card` class contains many members. I have two classes that derive from `Card` called `BlueCard` and `RedCard`. To visualize this:

```
public abstract class Card{
    //many members
}

public class BlueCard : Card{
    //many members
}

 public class RedCard : Card{
    //many members
}
```

Now, suppose I have a class `Deck`. `Deck` needs to contain a single array of both `BlueCard` and `RedCard`. Is there a way to go about this?

Comment: Make an array of Card and then cast to whatever type you need like *var value = array[0] as BlueCard;* -- if the result is null then the value is of *RedCard* and thus you should do the same but with *RedCard*. There's not really a "pretty" way to do this in my opninion. If you could avoid having to cast and simply use *Card* that would be the best. Seeing as *Card* is abstract you could easily do it with abstract methods.

Comment: @Bauss Thanks! That's what I was thinking. Let me ask you this: what if `Card` was an interface instead of an abstract class? Would I make an array of `ICard` and do the same thing?

Comment: Yeah it would be the exact same pattern.

Comment: Your overall question is valid. But if you're sticking to this card domain, I'd say just have a single Card class, then have a separate enum property for the color. I don't think inheritance is buying you anything here.

Comment: @mason I'd say it depends on the differences between the various types/classes.  I'm using the method described below myself, where the main class (Card class in OP's case) contains generic properties, while the derived classes contains specific properties related to each derived class.

Comment: @mason I was just using color names for the sake of brevity; there are many more reasons why inheritance is necessary for this case. I was trying to illustrate that there was a difference between the derived classes. Maybe color names wasn't the best example of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this approach in a similar situation myself, where an ElementGroup object contains a collection of objects that are either of type Element or of a type deriving from Element.  I think something like this should suit your case:

```
public class Deck {
    public Deck() {
        _cardArray = new Card[52];
    }

    private Card[] _cardArray;

    public void DrawCard(int cardNumber) {
        var card = _cardArray[cardNumber];
        if (card.GetType() == typeof(Card)) {
            // Do something
        }
        else if (card.GetType() == typeof(BlueCard)) {
            // Do something
        }
        else if (card.GetType() == typeof(RedCard)) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```